# In the 100, How did the little girl survive the end of Season 4?

Tags: the-100

At the 4th season finale of the 100, Clarke is together with a young girl, which I think is her daughter.

Clarke had previously gone through a bone marrow transplant in order to acquire radiation immunity. I don't think this procedure is hereditary. For this reason I cannot understand why would her daughter survive the radiation.

Who do you think this girl is? How did she survive, considering detrimental effects of radiation over a fetus?

Comment: I have edited the spoiler out of the title (It has taken me so long to get on to those last three episodes, I personally didnt care, but it does seem to be a spoiler). I actually had to double check to confirm *why* you would think Clarke had a daughter, and the plot synopsis I read states that the season *ends* with "Clarke standing with a young nightblood girl".

Comment: Could you confirm this? If we know the girl is nightblood, this supports that it is Clarkes daughter, but it should *also* tell you why she could survive radiation; the real question should be "how can a nightblood survive radiation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that Maddie is a Nightblood but there's no *specific* indication that she is Clarke's daugher (barring advanced aging) since she is clearly more than 6 years old (less pregnancy time).

[image]

Jason Rothenburg, producer of The 100...

> We wanted a reveal that Clarke survived and that her Nightblood kicked in, and she's now essentially — or so we think for the first couple of minutes of that final pop-out at the end — the lone survivor on the planet. Her friends... we know they made it to space, but she doesn't know whether or not they made it. We also know there's a group of 1200 led by Octavia (Marie Avgeropoulos) in the bunker, but Clarke is the lone survivor on the planet. **And then we reveal she's found Maddy, this Nightblood child.** Clearly, there's a maternal connection between the two of them when we reveal her in the end.
>
> ...
>
> They have been together for years when we first see them. She's been with Maddy alone for a number of years; longer than she was ever on the ground with anybody. So it's going to be a very powerful bond and a huge part of season five.
>
> <sup>[Hollywood Reporter](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/100-season-4-finale-explained-1007037)</sup>

**Found** does not indicate a daughter at least not a birth-daughter.

Indeed...at another interview...Rothenberg confirms

> The mother-daughter vibe that you pick up on in that scene is real. **(It’s not her biological child; I think it’s fairly obvious that the kid is too old for that.)** But she is a nightblood. Clarke was alone until she found Madi. When we find them together in [episode] 413, they have been together already for a number of years and are relying on each other and surviving together.
>
> <sup>[EW.com](http://ew.com/tv/2017/05/24/the-100-season-4-finale-explained/)</sup>

As for who Maddy/Madi (the spelling varies) is and where she comes from is yet to be revealed in S5.

Since we know she is older than the "Praimfaya" radiation storm and a nightblood, how she survived the *radiation* seems obvious.

In another interview with Rothenburg he stated..

> Nightblood is highly resistant to radiation, and obviously high levels of radiation are coming. As it turns out — **Becca** knew this — the flame itself emitted radiation. The human body needed to have resistance to that radiation, so she **designed it in the serum to give that anti-radiation ability**. Now, 100 years later, nightblood has become genetic, and it’s passed down. It’s a recessive gene, so it skips generations, and it’s very rare, but those who have it find themselves suddenly immune to this thing that’s coming.
>
> <sup>[EW.com](http://ew.com/tv/2017/02/15/the-100-jason-rothenberg-season-4-episode-3/)</sup>